# java - input from a file using scanner and a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I have a file `file.txt` which contains data in the form

```
integer n
title1
authorName1 authorSurname1
...
title n
authorNamen authorSurnamen
integer m
userName1 userSurname1
...
userNamem userSurnamem
```

What I'm trying to do is scan the first integer, then scan the whole title line as one string, author name and surname as separate strings, then loop the process n number of times. Then I want to scan the second integer, read the username and surname as separate strings, and loop this m number of times.
My current attempt (not best, can't remember how I had it before) looks like this:

```
public void readFile()
{
    int n=0;
    int m=0;
    while(fileReader.hasNextInt()) {
        n = fileReader.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<=n; i++) {
            while(fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
                 String bookTitle = fileReader.nextLine();
                 String authorFirstName = fileReader.next();
                 String authorSurname = fileReader.next();
                 ArrayList<Book>.add(new Book(bookTitle,authorFirstName,authorSurname));
                }
            }
        m = fileReader.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<=n; i++) {
            while(fileReader.hasNext()) {
                String userFirstName = fileReader.next();
                String userSurname = fileReader.next();
                ArrayList<User>.add(new User(userFirstName,userSurname));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I can't get it to output it as I want. I'm new to using scanner and that combined with a for loop has melted my brain a bit

Comment: Note that your code doesn't print anything, so you can't have any output. It also doesn't compile, so you can't even run it. You need to create a list, and then add books to that list: `List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>(); ... bookList.add(new Book(...));`